# How do I auto-mount a SMB share on OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, mount, smb, automount

How do I auto-mount a SMB share on OS X ?

I know how to mount it using GUI: Cmd-K on Finder but I want a solution that would restore them after reboot/relogin.

This questions applies to latest OS X, 10.8